# how to set RTF from WinForms to WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

how to set RTF from WinForms to WPF `RichTextBox`.
(Not by `TextRange.Load()`).

I have a string variable which has rtf text.
I want to set this variable to wpf ritch text box.

Comment: May I ask why you refuse TextRange.Load()?

Comment: because TextRange is used for to manipulate text within a range.
But i want to replace ritch text box text with rtf text.
there must be a method of doing this without TextRange.Load().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
ritchTextBox.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: This still uses `TextRange.Load()` (`Selection` is a `TextRange`)