# Extracting raw RTF from a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, rtf

There's got to be a better way to do this than what I'm doing.

I'm trying to extract the raw RTF from a WPF RichTextBox.  Well, really I'm trying to take a bunch of my custom classes and turn it into an RTF string, but I'm using a RichTextBox to do it because I don't particularly want to write my own RTF library.

The method I'm using (modified from something first seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003984/how-to-set-rtf-from-winforms-to-wpf-richtextbox) and used to extract XML [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601838/get-rtf-from-richtextbox)) is as follows:

```
RTB.Selection.Save(memstream, DataFormats.Rtf);
memstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var sr = new StreamReader(memstream);
var myText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This works, but seems ridiculously clumsy.  And I'm worried about the performance implications on large amounts of text.  Is there a better way?  (For the purpose of this question, let's assume that I can't use the WinForms RichTextBox.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542850/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-a-richtextbox) question.

```
string mpic = @"{\pict\pngblip\picw" + 
    img.Width.ToString() + @"\pich" + img.Height.ToString() +
    @"\picwgoal" + width.ToString() + @"\pichgoal" + height.ToString() + 
    @"\bin " + str + "}"
```